# NHibernate 3.3 Linq calling user defined function with bit parameter and bit result

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm extending the NHibernate Linq provider and i wish to call a user defined that has both bit parameter[s] and return type.

Here's the SQL user defined function signature:

```
 FUNCTION f_DocumentsFreeTextSearch
 (
     @docId int,
     @searchString varchar(8000),
     @searchTitle bit
 )
 RETURNS bit
```

Here's the "fake" extension method used for Linq usage:

```
public static class DialectExtensions
{
    public static bool FreeText(this Document doc, string searchString, bool searchTitle)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's my LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry

```
public sealed class ExtendedLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public ExtendedLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
    {
            DialectExtensions.FreeText(null, null, true)),
            new FreeTextGenerator());
    }
}
```

And here's my generator:

```
public class FreeTextGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public FreeTextGenerator()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[]
                               {
                                   ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() => DialectExtensions.FreeText(null, null, true))
                               };
    }

    #region Overrides of BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        return treeBuilder.MethodCall("dbo.f_documentsfreetextsearch", arguments.Select(a => visitor.Visit(a).AsExpression()).ToArray());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This is the desired usage:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanFreeText()
    {
        var query = SessionHolder.Current.Query<Document>();
        var list = query.Where(d => d.FreeText("giorno", true)).ToList();            
    }
```

First problem: the above code causes an InvalidCastException:

> Test method App.Tests.NHMapping.CanFreeText threw exception: 
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlMethodCall' to type
>   'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'.

Solved this way (not elegant but it works):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanFreeText()
    {
        var query = SessionHolder.Current.Query<Document>();
        var list = query.Where(d => d.FreeText("giorno", true) == true).ToList();            
    }
```

Now NHibernate executes the query, but the generated SQL is wrong:

> Test method App.Tests.NHMapping.CanFreeText threw exception: 
>   NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query [
>   select [...] from dbo.DOCUMENTS document0_ where case when
>   dbo.f_documentsfreetextsearch(document0_.IDDOCUMENT, @p0, @p1=1) then
>   1 else 0 end=@p2 ]   Name:p1 - Value:giorno  Name:p2 - Value:True 
>   Name:p3 - Value:True [SQL: select [...] from dbo.DOCUMENTS document0_
>   where case when dbo.f_documentsfreetextsearch(document0_.IDDOCUMENT,
>   @p0, @p1=1) then 1 else 0 end=@p2] --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Please not that the function call in the generated SQL has @p1=1 as third parameter, and that the WHERE clause is an inline CASE instead of

> dbo.f_documentsfreetextsearch(document0_.IDDOCUMENT, @p0, @p1) = 1

as i expected.

If i change in my C# code the bool parameter and return type into Int32, everything just work well (but still not very elegant).

Any idea of how to get desired syntax to work?

Thanks in advance

Claudio

PS: sorry for lots of code and errors' text :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you hit the same [bug NH-2839](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2839?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3aactivity-stream-issue-tab) as i did when using usertype for boolean property. not much you can do about it now until this is fixed.